How to install Spek on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble
I tooked a day to figure out if Spek is avaliable on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble. The answer is yes, it is working and most likely on all the sub division as well, as I has tested it on Linux Lite 7.0(based on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble). Despite the github page didn't include Ubuntu Noble. just follow the steps on https://github.com/alexkay/spek/blob/master/INSTALL.md
There might be problem with required packages, but you can solve all of them. I'm just here to say that it will work on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble, so don't waste a day like me trying to firgure out if it will work on Noble instead of try to get the required packages working

Steps on https://github.com/alexkay/spek/blob/master/INSTALL.md will work. In case that the page is deleted I will repeat the steps To build you will need wxWidgets and FFmpeg packages. On Debian/Ubuntu you also need development packages: libwxgtk2.8-dev, wx-common, libavcodec-dev and libavformat-dev Download the tar.xz package from page
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libwxgtk3.2-dev wx-common libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev
tar -xvf spek-0.8.5.tar.xz
cd spek-0.8.5
./configure
make

